# How to structure the tabs in a tabHost in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I'm crating a tabHost to contain all the content of my Android application in 3 tabs, should i create the content of the tab inside its linear layout or create the tab content in a separate fragment and include it in the tab layout?
And how to include the fragment inside a layout also?
Excuse me i'm a bit beginner to this.

Comment: tab host is kind of silently deprecated. probably not what you want to do. look into viewpager. this might help http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: Saw an answer here just telling the opposite, had me using the tabHost over the veiwPager!

Comment: that's weird. I can't imagine anyone recommending a tab host in 2015.

Answer (score 0):

you just add viewpagger for calling fragment

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
    private final String[] TITLES = { "Fragment1", "Fragment2", "Fragment2" };

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
         return TITLES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public  Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //return SuperAwesomeCardFragment.newInstance(position);            
        switch (position) {
        case 0:             
            return new JavaFragment1();     //this call you fragment1               
        case 1:             
            return new JavaFragment2();     //this call you fragment2       
        case 2:
            return new JavaFragment3();     //this call you fragment3       

        }
        return null;

    }


}
```